# Moving from Ultisnips to LuaSnip?

Tags: neovim, plugin-ultisnips, snippets, plugin-luasnip

I recently decided to switch my `init.vim` to `init.lua` as I'm using Neovim and opted to use LuaSnip over UltiSnips - previously, CoC autocomplete and UltiSnips were clashing over the same tab triggers. I'm currently writing a script to convert some of my LaTeX snippets from UltiSnips to the LuaSnip format. Most of the snippets are easy to convert; however, I came across a couple issues with a few specific types of snippets:

- Pre-expand snippets to expand tables and matrices. Theses use Python to generate the snippet based on input (e.g. I have `(b|p|some other letters)mat[r].[c]a?` to create a (optionally augmented) rxc matrix in LaTeX).
- Contextual Snippets, which depend on the environment and have functions to evaluate the environment (e.g. I have snippets to generate bullet points in `itemize` and `enumerate` environments in LaTeX).
- Auto-expand snippets (`iA` snippets in UltiSnips). Currently, snippets in LuaSnip require tab completion.

My question is: is it possible to move all these configurations to the LuaSnip format?

My thought is that instead of using Python to pre-expand snippets and to evaluate the environment, perhaps I could write the functions in Lua; however, I'm not sure if that is the correct approach. If anyone has done this before and has some insight, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling and some help on Reddit (huge thanks to L3MON4D3, u/Doltonius), here is what I have so far:

- Pre-expand is possible; however, this needs to be configured. L3MON4D3 has a set of matrix/table snippets and I'll try to see if I can modify those for my use as well (e.g. adding augments) and update the post when I have something working.
- For contextual snippets, this can be done using conditions. Creating a conditional will probably be quite similar to the Python functions used in UltiSnips, but now in Lua. Again, I'll update the post when I have created working functions.

Check if you are in a math environment:

```lua
local function math():
    return vim.api.nvim_eval('vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone()') == 1
end
```

- Auto-expand snippets can be done ([here](https://github.com/L3MON4D3/LuaSnip/blob/master/DOC.md#lua) for more info) Make sure to enable autoexpand in the config like so (just putting it here since I had a bit of a hard time finding out how to set the config):

```lua
ls = require "luasnip"
ls.config.set_config({
    enable_autosnippets = true,})
```

Comment: There's also a [Github discussion](https://github.com/L3MON4D3/LuaSnip/discussions/545) for more information.